# Certificate Signing SecurityAlgorithm from OID

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an OID defined like this `1.2.840.113549.1.1.1` [1]

I would like to get the corresponding `SecurityAlgorithms` value for the OID .

I have tried using the `AlgorithmIdentifier` class which takes an OID but it seems I cannot get the proper string that defines the algorithm from it.

This is what I am working from:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

var oid = new Oid(certificate.GetKeyAlgorithm());
var identifier = new AlgorithmIdentifier(oid);

// TODO How to get to the SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256 ("RS256") value? 
var todo = ???


Assert.Equal(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256, todo);
```

[1] https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Oid` Class under the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`

```
 Oid s1 = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");
 Console.WriteLine("Oid: {0}", s1.FriendlyName);
```

Gives the outputs as this

> Oid: RSA

Comment: Interesting but this is missing the "256" bits part. I thought I had it in the friendly name as well but it seems not :/

Comment: Actually if you look up the spec , the friendly name is officially termed as RSA encryption

Comment: I'm sure you are correct but in my question I am trying to resolve a string matching the ones found in `SecurityAlgorithms`. It seems I have to create my own mapping.